# Javascript Count array of object base on array value and use it on react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

this code works perfectly on my browser but when i applied it on react native i have an error of

> " Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError:
> obj.room_type_id.includes is not a function. (In
> 'obj.room_type_id.includes(id)', 'obj.room_type_id.includes' is
> undefined) "

```js
var data = [{
  "floor": "1st",
  "name": "NAME0",
  "room_type_id": ["Y", "B", "S", "N"],
  "status": "Available"
}, {
  "floor": "7",
  "name": "NAME54",
  "room_type_id": ["O", "G", "C", "S"],
  "status": "Available"
}, {
  "floor": "64",
  "name": "NAME2",
  "room_type_id": ["A", "S", "Q", "D"],
  "status": "Available"
}, {
  "floor": "Bddh",
  "name": "NAME3",
  "room_type_id": ["A", "X", "S", "D"],
  "status": "Available"
}, {
  "floor": "Vh",
  "name": "NAME1",
  "room_type_id": ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
  "status": "Available"
}, {
  "floor": "Dyd",
  "name": "NAME2",
  "room_type_id": ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
  "status": "Available"
}]

let id = "B";
let dataResult = data.filter((obj) => obj.room_type_id.includes(id)).length;


console.log(dataResult)
```

Comment: You need to check what `obj.room_type_id` returns: based on the error message, it does not appear to be an array when the `.filter()` callback is invoked.

Comment: it is Json object ! parse it to js then use it as you did

Answer (score 1):

Have a try by parsing the array object to the JSON object to use the array itteration methods.

```
let JSONData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
let dataResult = JSONData.filter((obj) => obj.room_type_id.includes(id)).length;
```